# Using external monitor in laptop but OS to see it as built-in

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, windows-registry

Is there any way to modify the registry to enable an external monitor but the OS still thinks is the built-in?

I want to use a larger monitor to watch the optimum application I have in my laptop which is not allowed by the application.
I'm trying to override this limitation so I can use this laptop as a second set top box.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "optimum resolution"? Wouldn't closing the laptop force Windows to use the external monitor as its primary screen?

Comment: Do you mean that your operating system thinks your external monitor is a built-in monitor and you want to stop that, or that your operating system thinks your external monitor is an external monitor but you want it to think it's built-in?

Comment: Are you getting an error when trying to watch on the external monitor?  You may be running into HDCP content protection.   If your monitor uses a VGA connection or does not support HDCP you will not be able to use it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Windows 7/8/8.1, hit Win-P, and select second screen only.

This will force Windows to use only the external monitor.

There is no need (nor any way) to do this via the registry.
The laptop has no concept of built-in or external, just a port with a monitor on it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have come up with a solution to this that seems to work.

I downloaded an app called Screenleap. It allows you to broadcast your screen to other parties via web browser.

1. Download and install Screenleap
2. Airplay Mac screen to Apple TV (as separate display)
3. In the separate display, open Safari.
4. Open Screenleap and set to "Share entire screen"
5. You will be directed to a link on Safari that will be broadcasting your screen. Open that in Safari on separate display.
6. Open the Optimum app.
7. Enjoy :)

I am hoping that this would also work with HDMI and I do not see a reason that it wouldnt. If anyone has any feedback, please let me know.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members.  However, this particular question was asking how to accomplish their goal on a Windows-based computer.  As a result, a potential solution that utilizes Apple-based software and hardware probably isn't beneficial to the question's author.  Please consider revising it accordingly.

Comment: Sorry about that. I used an Apple TV, but it should be the same using an HDMI cable. I will attempt that and revise my reply.